# ACF Relationship Field Bidirectional Meta Data

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, acfpro

I have an issue here.

I have 2 custom post types: Machines and Accessories.

I added the relationship field to Accessories Post so I can add any Machines related to it.

Now when I check the return array in my Accessories, I have a relationship Meta Data with an array ID value to every Machines so I can display all related accessories in my Machines Single Post.

For now it's fine but the problem is I need to display in another page a list of all Machines that contains at least 1 accessories. I have nothing in my Machines Meta Data. Is there any solution for that?

I use WP_query to display all my Machines but it shows all my Machines. Is there a way to show only the Machines with an Accessories relationship?

The Relationship Field is not Bidirectional?

Thank you!

---

**Here the page structure:**

- Machines Listing Page

  - Machine Single Post
- Accessories Listing Page

  - Accessories Single Post

In my **Accessories Listing Page** I have a filter by Machines. I can list all my Machines here with WP_query but it shows all my available Machines. I want to hide and show only the Machines that have at least an Accessories related to it. Some Machines don't have Accessories related to it so I displayed a text message in the loop listing saying there is no accessories for this Machines but instead of showing a text message I just want to hide the Machines completely in my filter...

Here is the code of **Accessories Listing Page**:

```
<div class="taxonomy-accessory-container brands">
  <h2>Brands & Models</h2>

  <ul>
    
    <?php
      // Get all the terms from taxonomy
      $terms = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'brands',
        'hide_empty' => true
      ));
    ?>

    <?php if ($terms): ?>
      
      <?php foreach ($terms as $term): ?>
        <li>
          <h3><?= esc_html($term->name); ?></h3>

          <ul>
            <?php
              $args_product = array(
                'post_type' => 'products',
                'tax_query' => array(
                  array (
                    'taxonomy' => 'brands',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => $term->slug
                  )
                ),
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order'   => 'ASC'
              );

              $query_product = new WP_Query($args_product);
            ?>

            <!-- Loop -->
            <?php if ($query_product->have_posts()): ?>
              <?php while ($query_product->have_posts()): $query_product->the_post(); ?>
                <?php
                  global $post;
                  $slug = $post->post_name;
                ?>
                <li><a href="<?= get_site_url(); ?>/models-accessories/?model=<?= $slug; ?>&amp;id=<?= get_the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
              <?php endwhile; ?>
              <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            <?php endif; ?> <!-- End Loop -->
          </ul>
        </li>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      
    <?php endif; ?>
    
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share the code which you did

Comment: Hi @FullStop, thanks for your reply, I added the code in the post. Thank you!